# How to send to Flutter's EventChannel from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, flutter, kotlin, dart

I sucessfully setted a event channel between Kotlin and Flutter. However, I need another Kotlin thread to be able to use this Event Channel. I only found tutorials on how to launch things from the Event Channel inside the `onListen` method, like making a counter that sends things every second.

How can I make another thread call `event.sucess(something)`?

Here's what I done:

```
   class MainActivity: FlutterActivity(){
   companion object {

    //this is called by another thread
    @JvmStatic
    private fun onEventChannel(b: ByteArray):Int {
        //How do I make this call events.success(b) on onListen?
    }
   //...
   override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, EVENT_CHANNEL).setStreamHandler(object : EventChannel.StreamHandler {
            override fun onListen(args: Any, events: EventChannel.EventSink) {
                Log.d(TAG, "adding listener for $EVENT_CHANNEL")
                events.success(true)
            }

            override fun onCancel(args: Any) {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancelling listener for $EVENT_CHANNEL")
            }
        })
```